The distribution of $Z \exp(Z)$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
I am trying to find the expectation and variance of random variable
$$Z \exp(Z)$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. I was trying to approach the problem with moment generating function but got stuck in the process. Any ideas?

Your idea is a good one, since the MGF $M_Z(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tZ}]$ implies $$\frac{d}{dt} M_Z(t) = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{d}{dt}[e^{tZ}]\right] = \operatorname{E}[Ze^{tZ}].$$  To proceed further, please show your calculations.

Is there any reason to think there is a closed form? $f(x)=xe^x$ is not a $1-1$ function, which might make this hard.

@ThomasAndrews I believe you can actually write both the mean and the variance of $Ze^Z$ in terms of the first and/or second derivatives of the MGF of $Z$ evaluated at specific values of $t$. This does yield a closed form.

Of course, the moment generating function of $Ze^Z$ is $E[\exp(tZe^Z)],$ so it might be possible to use the moment generating function of $Z$ to compute $E(Ze^Z),$ that is only the first moment of $Ze^Z.$ @heropup

@ThomasAndrews I only gave a hint because the OP should show more work, but the method described can also be used to compute the variance.  I would just want to see what the OP has tried.

Indeed, for the mean its trivial. For variance we need $$\mathbb{E}[(Ze^{tZ})^2] = \mathbb{E}[Z^2e^{2tZ}] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{Z}{2}\frac{d}{dt}e^{2tZ}] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{2tZ}] = \frac{1}{4} \frac{d^2}{dt^2}M_Z(2t)$$  Then evaluate this at $t=1$. Thank you all!

There's no need to use a moment generating function when you can just compute the raw moments directly from the definition:
$$\begin{aligned}E[(Z e^Z)^n]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (z e^z)^n \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} dz\\
&=e^{n^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^n \frac{e^{-(z-n)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} dz\\
&=e^{n^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (z+n)^n \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} dz\\
&=e^{n^2/2}E[(Z +n)^n]
\end{aligned}$$
In particular, the first and second raw moments are $\sqrt{e}$ and $5e^2$ respectively.

+1. I agree. MGF is a bad idea.

Please do not answer questions with no effort shown.
